# Requested modules not available: vtkRendering

Tags: cmake, vtk

I have been trying to build VTK and run the first example in the tutorial,
the cone , but when I do

```
cmake .
```

I got the following Error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/lib/cmake/vtk-6.3/vtkModuleAPI.cmake:120 (message):
Requested modules not available:

vtkRendering
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/local/lib/cmake/vtk-6.3/VTKConfig.cmake:80 (vtk_module_config)
CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I am using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Tikanga).

Any suggestion would be appriciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, simply due to the fact that "vtkRendering" itself does not exist in recent versions of VTK (I'm using 6.3).
You should specify for example vtkRenderingOpenGL, or vtkRenderingQt, etc...

Hope it helps!